# C# SQL Select Query table parameter

Tags: c#, sql, db2

I am trying to select from a table where the table name is being assigned from a variable as im using two different tables. However it comes up with a DB2Exception Error.

```
db2Error = {"ERROR [42601] [IBM][AS] SQL0104N  An unexpected token \"'TABLENAME'\" was found following \"\".
```

This query is the one which causes the error - 
Table name is a string which has the names of the table.

```
string strUpdate = "SELECT COMMENT FROM '" + tableName + "' WHERE NUMBER = '" + strNumber + "' AND CODE = '" + c.Trim() + "' ";
```

This query works fine though -

```
 //  string strUpdate = "SELECT COMMENT FROM TABLE WHERE NUMBER = '" + strNumber + "' AND CODE = '" + c.Trim() + "'";
```

Is it possible to parametrise/use variable for the table name?

Comment: High risk of SQL injection detected!

Comment: Have you debugged your code and checked the value of 'tablename' ?
Show us the sql query string assigned to strUpdate. Is your table name Table???

Comment: Yes I'm aware of my SQL Injection vulnerability but need this problem to be solved first. And yes the table names are correct in tablename when debugging

Comment: Why do you have quotes around your table name? SQL injection risk aside, I figure that's your problem.

Comment: @dotctor The query should use parameters, yes, but not for the table name; that'll have the string treated as string data and escaped with quotes the same way it is now. The chance that _that's_ user input is low anyway. It's most likely a shared function used for a couple of similarly-structured tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL injection risk aside, the two shown queries *are simply not the same*.

The query you showed is

`string strUpdate = "SELECT COMMENT FROM TABLE WHERE NUMBER = "` etc.

However, the *code* you showed produces the following query:

`string strUpdate = "SELECT COMMENT FROM 'TABLE' WHERE NUMBER = "` etc.

The table name should simply not be in quotes. And given the fact you're not using parameters, this isn't even the parameter system's fault; the quotes are right there in your own query-constructing code. Just delete them.

Comment: Hi, Ive removed the '  ' quotes from either sides and it works fine. I have also taken into consideration all the SQL injection comments so thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using qoutes in your from statement? it should just simply be

```
select sysdate 
from dual;
```

Also use the SqlCommand class to add parameters in your selectstatement as follows.

```
string strUpdate = "SELECT COMMENT FROM @tablename WHERE NUMBER = @strnumber AND CODE = @c";
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(strUpdate , connection);
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tableName ", tableName );
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strNumber ", strNumber );
insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", c.trim());
```

Comment: Won't that still put quotes around the table name, given the fact it's added as string parameter?

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/